# Prefuse email visualization in jsp page

Tags: jsp, email, visualization, prefuse

We are working on a web application (dojo/jsf/spring/ibatis framework) and one of our jsp pages should show a force directed graph of email communications.
The graph should also be interactive. For example when a user clicks on a node(for ex person object), all the nodes that have direct relationship with the node(person) of interest should be highlighted with some color.

After doing a fair amount of research, I found prefuse a java based tool with email visualization capability which is built on swing and java2D.
I glanced through a tutorial and I have a question before I go ahead and start working with the tutorial.

Is it possible to have email visualization in jsp page using prefuse?
Can anyone give me high level view of how it can be done? For example, is it going to be an image from server shown in the jsp?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

While it would be possible to include a prefuse visualization as a Java applet in a JSP page, I would rather recommend to use **D3** or **ProtoVis** for web-based visualizations.

Examples with force-directed layout:

- http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html

[image]

- http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/force.html